# Hide BackButton in UINavigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

i am pushing a View om RootView controller ,i get the navigation bar with back button which is navigate to rootviewcontoller,but i don't need this back button.i pout this code in the viewcontoller to hide the back button

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

so i get the hidden back button,but here is the problem,i need leftnavigationbar button to show something,when i write the above code ,the letbarbutton also hidden from the view.becz the leftbarbutton act as the back button.

My need is to block the letbarbutton to become a back button when push from the rootviewcontroller,i didn't need a navigation back to rootviewcontoller.But defenitly need leftbarbutton there for my need in the view.

How can it possible to do?.Please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

it works for me

Comment: in the viewDidLoad methode of the viewController where you want to hide the bacButton

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the letbarbutton and add no action to it?

Comment: what?i didn't underdtsand wht u mean

Comment: ,i need the action for letbr button,but when i push from root view,the letbarbutton turns back button.

Comment: "the letbarbutton turns back button" it's really odd. I always need to add an pop view action to do this. If not, it will not get back to the root view.